# Как сделать чтобы слова в меню навигации растянулись по всему обёму (как на картинке ниже)

Tags: html, css

А также как сделать чтобы картинка не конфликтовала с текстом и её можно было перенести прям под поле навигации, не мешая тексту.
PS: Извините за кривой код :3. И да если ктото знает что надо сделать чтобы фотографии отображались в браузере подскажите пожалуйста.

Что должно было получиться: [image: MDN]

Что получилось:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:
CSS

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    font: 1.2em / 1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  img {
      max-width: 100%;
      display: block;
  }
  
  .logo {
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    margin-left:150px ;
    max-width: 980px;
    
  }
  
  .grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    max-width: 980px;
  }
  li {
  display: inline;
  
}
  nav {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    position: sticky;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    ;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .5em 1em;
  }
  
  .photos {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    
  }

  .feature {
      width: 200px;
  }
  h2 {
      position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right: 50px;
      
  }
```

```html
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Layout Task</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>
  <h1 class="logo">  My exciting website! </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Our history</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main class="grid">
    <article>
      <h1>
        An Exciting Blog Post
      </h1>
      <img src="images/balloon-sq6.jpg" alt="placeholder" class="feature">
      <p>Veggies es bonus vobis, proinde vos postulo essum magis kohlrabi welsh onion daikon amaranth tatsoi tomatillo melon
        azuki bean garlic.</p>

      <p>Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens
        dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.</p>

      <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon
        napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko.
        Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram
        corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress.
        Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>

      <p>Nori grape silver beet broccoli kombu beet greens fava bean potato quandong celery. Bunya nuts black-eyed pea prairie
        turnip leek lentil turnip greens parsnip. Sea lettuce lettuce water chestnut eggplant winter purslane fennel azuki
        bean earthnut pea sierra leone bologi leek soko chicory celtuce parsley jícama salsify.</p>

      <p>Celery quandong swiss chard chicory earthnut pea potato. Salsify taro catsear garlic gram celery bitterleaf wattle
        seed collard greens nori. Grape wattle seed kombu beetroot horseradish carrot squash brussels sprout chard.</p>

    </article>

    <aside>
      <h2>
        Photography
      </h2>
      <ul class="photos">
        <li>
          <img src="images/balloon-sq1.jpg" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/balloon-sq2.jpg" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/balloon-sq3.jpg" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/balloon-sq4.jpg" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/balloon-sq5.jpg" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
      </ul>

    </aside>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

PSS: Не забейте меня тапками:3

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для

```
ul {
   min-width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо стало лучше, о "justify-content: space-between;" я вообще не знал(:, но "min-widht: 100%;" неактивно.

Comment: Если вам был полезен мой ответ, поставте пожалуйста на нем зеленую галочку) ```min-width``` - опечатка) исправьте,  все должно заработать)

Comment: А как поставить зелёную галочку? Извините я новенький на этом сайте.

Comment: мі сейчас с вами комментируем мой ОТВЕТ, верно? Вот если вы наведете курсор мыши на этот ответ, то увидите серую галочку. если вы на нее нажмете, галочка станет зеленой)

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  font: 1.2em / 1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  max-width: 980px;
}

.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  max-width: 980px;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

nav {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 100px;
  position: sticky;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

.photos {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
}

.photos li {
  max-width: calc(50% - 8px);
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
}

.feature {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

article {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Layout Task</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="logo"> My exciting website! </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Our history</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main class="grid">
    <article>
      <h1>
        An Exciting Blog Post
      </h1>
      <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder" class="feature">
      <p>Veggies es bonus vobis, proinde vos postulo essum magis kohlrabi welsh onion daikon amaranth tatsoi tomatillo melon azuki bean garlic.</p>

      <p>Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.</p>

      <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water
        spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts
        nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>

      <p>Nori grape silver beet broccoli kombu beet greens fava bean potato quandong celery. Bunya nuts black-eyed pea prairie turnip leek lentil turnip greens parsnip. Sea lettuce lettuce water chestnut eggplant winter purslane fennel azuki bean earthnut
        pea sierra leone bologi leek soko chicory celtuce parsley jícama salsify.</p>

      <p>Celery quandong swiss chard chicory earthnut pea potato. Salsify taro catsear garlic gram celery bitterleaf wattle seed collard greens nori. Grape wattle seed kombu beetroot horseradish carrot squash brussels sprout chard.</p>

    </article>

    <aside>
      <h2>
        Photography
      </h2>
      <ul class="photos">
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
      </ul>

    </aside>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```